# Logging data found with different id's on the same line

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

I am trying to log all title, href, and meta information on a youtube channels video tab. So I went to the chrome dev console and typed the code below. It currently logs the meta information right but the title and href just logs duplicates of previous loop. The way I am getting the title, href and meta information is correct the only issue is with the way I looped. I have a loop inside another loop because I want to log all the information of the same video in one line but while the title and href can be found with the same id the meta information is found with a different id. How can I fix my code so that I can correctly log the title, href and meta information of the same video in one line. Thanks in advance.

**To replicate:** `go to youtube` **=>** `go to a specific youtube channel` **=>** `go to the video tab of their channel` **=>** `(Optional) Write code to scroll all the way down, to get more data` **=>** `Then paste in my code to console and run`

```js
$('.ytd-grid-video-renderer').find('#video-title').each(function() {
  const v1 = $(this).attr('title')
  $('.ytd-grid-video-renderer').find('#metadata-line').each(function() {
    const v2 = $(this).text()
    console.log(`title: ${v1}, meta: ${v2}}`)
  })
})
```

**update based on @james code:** But there is still duplicates getting pushed to the array. How can the code be fixed so that duplicates don't get pushed to the array?

```js
let myArr = []
$('.ytd-grid-video-renderer').each(function() {
  const v1 = $(this).find('#video-title').attr('title');
  const v2 = $(this).find('#metadata-line').text();
  if (v1 && v2) {
    myArr.push(`{title: ${v1}, meta: ${v2}}`)
  }
})

console.log(myArr)
```

Comment: `urls2 = $$('div');` This returns all divs on the whole page, not those that are within a parent container.  Not sure what `$$` is, jQuery?  If so, try `urls2 = $$(v).find('div')`

Comment: @James take a look at my updated code. Same problem but modern jquery

Comment: Are you trying to locate the divs within the h3?  Right now your line starting with `$('div').find` is going to pull all divs from the whole page.

Comment: @James forgot to change that take a look at updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one set of output per "ytd-grid-video-renderer" I believe, so there should be a single loop over those elements.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ytd-grid-video-renderer').forEach(function(el) {
  const v1 = el.querySelector('#video-title');
  const v2 = el.querySelector('#metadata-line');
  if (v1 && v2) {
    console.log(`title: ${v1.getAttribute("title")}, meta: ${v2.innerText}}`)
  }
})
```

Comment: it kinda works. It gets the data correctly but there is a lot of ```title: undefined, meta: ``` results. Can you set an if statement to validate of the required element exists first?

Comment: can you please take a look at the update above

Comment: I removed the jquery.  Now it checks if the video-title and the metadata-line exist and only displays something if they both do.

Comment: This works perfectly but when I push it to an array duplicates get pushed in. How can I avoid that? Or is the better way to filter the array then remove duplicates?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates